# Rotate on hover and stop after animation using only CSS3?

Tags: css, animation, rotation, onhover

I've come across this post//
[Slide out text from an image using CSS on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712295/slide-out-text-from-an-image-using-css-on-hover)

The CSS works perfectly, except I would like for the animation to stop after it's rotated once.

Is this possible? If so how can I accomplish this?

HTML:

```
@-webkit-keyframes rotate {
    from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    to { 
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes rotate {
    from {
      -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
    }
    to { 
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
}

.srch_btn:hover {   
    -webkit-animation-name:            rotate; 
    -webkit-animation-duration:        0.5s; 
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;

    -moz-animation-name:            rotate; 
    -moz-animation-duration:        0.5s; 
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `animation-iteration-count:  infinite` to `2`.